# Программное добавление TextView и EditText

Tags: java, android

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addName);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addLayout);

Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(queryText, null);
cursor1.moveToFirst();
for (int i = 0; i < cursor1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    TextView nameCol = new TextView(this);
    EditText inner = new EditText(this);
    nameCol.setText(" " + cursor1.getColumnName(i) + ": ");
    nameCol.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    nameCol.setTextSize(23);
    nameCol.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(nameCol);
    inner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(inner,i);
}
cursor1.close();
```

По коду должны по-очереди добавляться Н пар TextView и EditText, но добавляются сначала все TextView, а потом все EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут

```
 layout.addView(inner,i);
```

EditText добавляются на позиции 0,1,2...n, а TextEdit будут в хвосте.

Comment: а можно как-то задать каждой эдитке id, чтобы потом извлекать данные?

Comment: Задавайте через `setId(int)`, согласно документации это должно быть положительное число. За уникальность отвечаете вы, система ругаться не будет в случае дубликатов.

Comment: Начитая с API17 есть метод `View.generateViewId()`, если лень самому id придумывать.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте так, без индекса для еditText

```
 nameCol.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(nameCol);
        inner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(inner);
```